# How can I make Firefox (or any other Android browser) automatically redirect me/automatically change URLs?

Tags: browser, firefox-for-android

There are at least two cases where I'd like my phone's browser to automatically replace all URLs that fit a pattern: `www.reddit.com/XXX` --> `old.reddit.com/XXX`, and `XXX.fandom.com` --> `XXX.breezewiki.com`. I assume this can't be that uncommon a request. Ideally this would work in the os's built in google results, firefox, chrome, etc. but I could live with it only working in Firefox. I can't find any tool or FF extension to do this on Android at all. Does such a tool exist? I'm on a Pixel 6a if it matters.

Comment: I haven't used Firefox on Android for a little bit (been meaning to try it again).  Can it use Web Extensions?  If so, you can use the excellent `Redirector` Web Extension.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket i'm afraid not :( i'm using Redirector on desktop, but there's no version of it for the Android app. (weirdly, it HAS a page in the /android/ directory of the add-ons site, but my device says it's incompatible and nothing in the docs mentions android so i think the listing is just incorrect. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/redirector/ )

Comment: Just to clarify, Firefox for Android does not currently support the majority of Firefox desktop Web Extensions?  IIRC, Firefox for Android does support about a dozen of them, but it might still be limited to just those specific extensions.  I still really want to spend more time looking into more details on this topic... but time has been limited.